Docker with PHP - Class "Redis" not found
Dump extension_loaded('redis') returns true but I get

Class "Redis" not found

I have a simple docker file like
FROM php:7.1.32-fpm-alpine3.10

ENV PHPREDIS_VERSION 5.2.2

RUN docker-php-source extract && \
  curl -L -o /tmp/redis.tar.gz https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/archive/$PHPREDIS_VERSION.tar.gz && \
  tar xfz /tmp/redis.tar.gz && \
  rm -r /tmp/redis.tar.gz && \
  mv phpredis-$PHPREDIS_VERSION /usr/src/php/ext/redis && \
  docker-php-ext-install redis

ENTRYPOINT ["php-fpm"]


Have you tried tacking on docker-php-ext-enable redis to the end?

You can use pecl to install redis then use the docker-php-ext-enable as normal like so: RUN pecl install -o -f redis; rm -rf /tmp/pear; docker-php-ext-enable redis; unless you want a specific 5.2.2 version

You have one big command, it's unclear where it fails to do what you expect. I suggest dropping an "ls -al" command between each of the above so you can see the reality and compare to expectations.

@Sammitch install calls enable under the hood.

@Jaquarh pecl/redis requires PHP 7.4 I would need the 5.2.2

@CaptainChaos these are just independent commands ran in continuation?

After each of the above commands, try running "ls -al" so see the contents of the directory you are working in, I suspect something is giving a different output than you expect.
